# Windows 10 Desktop PC will not wake up at all

Tags: boot, windows-10, sleep, wake-up

Yesterday my Dell Desktop PC with Windows 10 64-bit was refusing to wake from its sleep state.  I finally got it to come on by not only powering it off, but unplugging it and waiting a few seconds.  It came back from cold boot, but that is better than nothing.  I then, as many suggested, ran the power troubleshooter.

This morning it will not show anything on the display.  When I power up, I hear the diskdrive work, I see a little outboard USB hub light up.  On my monitor I am able to see the message that no signal is coming from my PC, so I figure my monitor is ok (and is set not to VGA or HDMI, but auto).

I have tried unplugging and trying to boot with F2 held down, and again with F8.  Nada, nichts, nichevo.  I booting with a linux ISO in the disk drive, and with one in a USB port.  Again, nothing.

Up until yesterday everything, including sleep, was working fine.

Might I ask if anyone has any ideas?  And thanks.

Comment: Do you have a Video card on hand? or a friend that could let you test it out and see if the onboard video is just not putting out a signal?

Answer (score 0):

The no signal message on the monitor makes me think that it may be a connection problem between monitor and computer. It's possible that something may be heating up or shaking a connection loose. If your monitor is connected via VGA/HDMI cable, have you tried replacing the cable with a new/different one?

Comment: Thanks, UnixCurious.  Not another cable,no.  I did disconnect the cable I have, and the monitor then said "there is no VGA cable attached."  When I put the cable back in place, it said once again "there is no signal coming from your computer." From that I am guessing that the cable is OK, because the monitor is recognizing it is a VGA cable (right?)

Comment: Well I'd say to try with different cables, both HDMI and VGA. They're pretty cheap, and it never hurts to have extras around if you don't already.

Comment: Also, make sure to check the cable for visible damage/defects.